# log4j2 2.10.0 will not deploy on jboss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

Needed to update our log4j2 from 2.7 to 2.10.0 to get JMS retries working.
When I try to deploy the ear with the 2.10.0 files, jboss is complaining with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource: Provider 
org.apache.logging.log4j.util.EnvironmentPropertySource not a subtype"},
```

We are also excluding the default jboss logger from our app

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">

    <deployment>

        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />         
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
```

These are the jars in my ear's lib folder for logging:

```
lib/log4j-api.jar
lib/log4j-core.jar
lib/log4j-slf4j-impl.jar
lib/log4j-web.jar
lib/slf4j-api.jar
lib/slf4j-ext.jar
```

Any suggestions?  Maybe there is another new file I have to exclude?

Comment: You could add the following to your jboss-deployment-structure.xml (included in the war):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <!--
      Prevent that the server add automatically dependencies -->
      <!-- Exclude all logging dependencies so we can use log4j2 -->
      <exclusions>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />

Comment: <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
      </exclusions> 
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Comment: Then you could include the log4j2 jar in your application and put the log4j2 config file in a file system folder if you add an appropriate module definition.

This all depends though on the logging api that your application is using - e.g. against which api it is compiled. If you can change it I'd suggest to use slf4j that would be the most flexible solution.

Comment: @anup I am already excluding those files.

Comment: Do you exclude those dependencies for the sub-deployments too? Also it may just be easier to exclude the logging subsystem instead of each dependency.

Comment: Yes, I did (did not show in question).  How does one exclude the entire log subsystem?

Comment: While this is for 6.4, it shows how to exclude a sub-system [Development guide - Exclude a subsystem from a deployment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/development_guide/exclude_a_subsystem_from_a_deployment)